# Trello is no longer sending me email notifications whenever a board member posts a comment

Tags: trello

Trello is no longer sending me email notifications whenever a board member posts a comment
Do you know why?
I want to go back to getting an email about any action on the board.
Any advice?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. For bug reports, send an email to support@trello.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed - this bug was around for a day or so.